# DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing options to #find is deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

In my message model I have method to read a message, I use it in Message Controller. But something's worng with this method because when i run the tests i have error:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing options to #find is deprecated. Please build a scope and then call #find on it. (called from readingmessage at /home/mateusz/rails4/Bloggers/app/models/message.rb:21)
```

This is my method:

```
def self.readingmessage(id, reader)
 message = find(id, :conditions => ["sender_id = ? OR recepient_id = ?",    reader,  reader])
if message.read_at.nil? && (message.recepient.id==reader)
  message.read_at = Time.now
  message.save!
end
  message
end
```

Comment: If Dylan's answer helped you, don't forget to accept it by clicking the little checkmark beside his answer (right under the voting buttons) :)

Comment: Yes.... Please do accept the answer. If the answer didn't solve your problem please share the solution that did. If there has not been a solution then let us know and we will try to find a better one.

Answer (score 4):

You would be using `where` instead:

```
message = where("sender_id = ? OR recepient_id = ?", reader, reader).find(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try arel syntax:

```
message = where('sender_id = ? OR recepient_id = ?', reader, reader).find(id)
```

Worth looking at:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the same tutorial I'm using to build out my messaging system. Instead of just `find` or `where` (it'll only retrieve an active relation object), do:

```
self.find(id, :conditions => ["sender_id = ? OR recepient_id = ?", reader, reader])
```